# Object reference not set to an instance of an object? Having problem setting my script from 2d to 3d ;-;

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, 2d, nullreferenceexception

[Here ist my whole script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66KYX.png)

This is the Line where it seems like I have a problem with. Since im not super experienced I took this code out from a 2D Game.

Vector3Int gridPosition = tileMapReadcontroller.GetGridPosition(Input.mousePosition, mousePosition: true);

Not sure if this is a problem when im trying to insert this in a 3D world :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)